# Notification push server vs simple HTTP POST/GET

Tags: node.js, notifications

I am currently making API for a product where we read the users calendar and remind them (during chrome - can change this) to frequently take breaks (when there isnt a meeting)

These reminders are like notifications. 
In my opinion, we need to push a notification like : http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/

I am not sure how to trigger it. I know how to write APIs but not sure about the trigger part.

My co-worker says there shouldn't be any web sockets and told me to refer to the following : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream

I am a bit confused and I think we need web sockets. Am I incorrect about this? Also, any recommendations on how I can trigger my API? I don't want to do an ajax call every minute or so (in the front end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use socket.io. Websockets are working on both directions. In other words you do not howe to refresh the page or post a ajax request in order to invoke an event in the client side. Examples on the official web site will be sufficient I guess.
http://socket.io/docs/

If the docs are not sufficient let me explain with an example. Whenever you should push notification in backend side you may have something like this

```
    io.to(socketid).emit('notification', "You have new notifications");
```

This socket id is unique for every connection. You can keep track of it by using somekind of hashmap. Key may be the user id and the value may be the socket id for that user. Whenever you call this chunk of code on the clientside this pair of code will be invoked:

```
    socket.on('notification', function(msg){
               /*stuff*/
    }
```

here msg is just a string with value You have new notifications. You may pass whatever object you want.

Comment: The thing is it is just notification. There is NO page. I am aware about socket.io thanks for the recommendation tho!

Comment: There is no need to send a page. You may pass whatever object you want.